DuckDB: Error: Parser Error: syntax error at or near "into"
Running following commands in nodejs - duckdb and getting following error
create table runs_4fd1 (config JSON, sample JSON)

insert into runs_4fd1 values ('null', null)

Error
Error: Parser Error: syntax error at or near "into"


I am running DuckDB nodejs library to create a table and then inserting values.
Note: on duckdb terminal these two commands work perfectly.

Are they separated by ;? Because it looks like they're not
